# Eclipse java debugger suddenly stops working?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, libgdx

I am using Eclipse Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1) with JRE7 and LibGDX 1.6.1 - The debugger was working nicely yesterday and it just stops working right at the first few lines of code.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "Scene2D";
        cfg.useGL30 = false;
        cfg.width = 480;
        cfg.height = 320;

        new LwjglApplication(new Main_Scene2D(), cfg);
    }
}
```

In the source code above, I can set a breakpoint at any line and step thru the rest of but  it does not stop at Main_Scene2D() as I set a breakpoint in there. The debug tab shows:

`Main [Java Application]`
`com.xxx.tutorials.libgdx.UI.Scene2D.Main at localhost:61386`
`Thread [main] (Running)`
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (Jan 20, 2016, 12:11:14 AM)`

Please help ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By pausing the debugger and resuming it, I figured out the execution is looping and waiting for Audio input (?) so I just add a new statement cfg.disableAudio in the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.title = "Scene2D";
    cfg.useGL30 = false;
    cfg.width = 480;
    cfg.height = 320;
    cfg.disableAudio = true;

    new LwjglApplic ation(new Main_Scene2D(), cfg);
}
```

and the debugger behaves as normal now. The problem is what happens to my Audio. That's a different story. Thanks.